# Should I move to Java SE 6 from 5.0?

Tags: java

I have code now running with Java J2SE 5.0. It runs good but I am now looking at using a later version of Java.

I have seen lots of information about new features with SE 6 but would appreciate if anyone could give me some suggestions as to the most important of these. Are there any real performance improvements or really good new features that I should look into.

Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371681/reasons-and-advantages-for-upgrading-to-java-6-for-a-non-technical-decider-at-th/3371725#3371725

Comment: Sun Java 5 is EOL already for atleast a couple of years. Unless you want to fork out $$$ for Java SE 5 Business Edition, you should not only be adopting Java 6, but also looking at a migration path to Java 7 in the next year or so. And um, Java 6 was released nearly 5 years back, so you're very late in asking this question.

Comment: While Java 6 has its advantages, you may want to wait for Java 7 becoming the standard Java download (currently it's available for developers). I think it wouldn't take long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any real performance improvements

Heck yes.  Java6 VMs are substantially quicker than Java5 VMs.  The new features are generally underwhelming, though.

Other than, Java5 is way past its end-of-life, and is no longer supported.

I strongly recommend upgrading, especially if the extra performance is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to switch, not only for performance reason but to take advantage and *learn* new features that new java version have to offer. It always take a long time to find, learn new stuff that made in java new versions, the earlier the better for you. Your programs will be stronger, shorter and you'll follow more innovation in IT.

With respect to that, it could be nice to have a look at the features that [java...7 will offer.](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/)

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: It's been many years since Java could be called "innovation in IT", I fear :(

Answer (score 0):

Once a release has been accepted in the community, you should always move to it for performance and security improvements.

From SE5 to SE6, there aren't too many new features. However, Swing performance was greatly enhanced as were the garbage collector algorithms. In general, this revision made application performance much faster.

Definitely upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Java SE 5 is almost 7 years old now. Version 6 has been around for almost 5 years.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29

With regards to language and APIs Java 6 did not change much, performance improvements and fixes are its main features.

Answer (score 0):

if your code works fine, and performance is acceptable.

keep it